# Unfortunately My-libgdx-game has stopped error

Tags: android, libgdx, runtime-error, launch

I tried to launch my android game to my android device (phone) and it keeps stopping..no errors shown in logcat but it does in the console...i have all the required build tools and versions (eclipse 4.4)..i need help!!!

Comment: so what's the error in console

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)